# Adding Whitespace Using str_pad in R

Tags: r, whitespace, stringr

I have a list of names and I'm trying to replace each item in the list with the same name but a single whitespace on either side. Each item in the list is an individual first name OR last name, but it's only one word. And I need to add exactly one space before or after.

e.g. I want "John" to become " John ".

I've been trying to use str_pad, with code that essentially looks like:

```
lst <- c("John", "James", "Sam")
names <- list()
for(i in lst){
    i <- str_pad(i, width = 3, side = "both")
    names <- append(i, names)
}
```

However, you need to know the length you want the final string to be for it to add only one space to each side. How would I modify this code to add exactly one space before and after the name?

I also tried the following, which won't run:

```
i <- str_pad(i, width = length(i)+2, side = "both")
```

I've played around with regex and gsub but I'm not super comfortable with it and haven't been able to been able to make it work.

Comment: Or just use `paste0`: `paste0(' ',lst,' ')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be simpler to use `sprintf` for this:

```
sprintf(" %s ",lst)
[1] " John "  " James " " Sam "
```

Answer (score 1):

We don't need a loop for this as `str_pad` is vectorized according to `?str_pad`

> Vectorised over string, width and pad.

```
library(stringr)
mx <- max(nchar(lst)) + 1
str_pad(lst, width = mx, side = "both")
#[1] " John " "James " " Sam  "
```